# Code to find max number from array

Tags: c

I wrote the following code to find the max number from a array of numbers. Apparently there is an error in my code.It is a segmentation error. Please help me identify it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void max(int n,int A[n]);

int main()
{
int n;
int A[n];
max(n,A[n]);
}

void max(int n,int A[n])
{
printf("Enter the number of elements you want in your array\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
int i;
printf("Enter the elements  in your array\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&A[i]);
}
int max=A[0];
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(A[i]>max)
    {
        max=A[i];
    }
}
printf("%d",max);
}
```

Comment: `n` is uninitialized. Array is unitialized. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: How is it unitialized?

Comment: `n` equals.. what? `A` is filled with .. what?

Comment: Oh, I see you attempt to do it in the function. But you "allocate" the array with `n` *before* it is set.

Comment: `void max(int n,int A[n]); ... int n;
int A[n];
max(n,A[n]);` implies code was compiled without warnings enabled.   `max(n,A[n])` attempts to pass an `int` as a pointer.  Save time, enable all warnings.

Answer (score 2):

```
int n;
int A[n];
```

You have to initialize `n` otherwise it contains garbage value. And now after this point you run into undefined behavior.

Correct code would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void printMax(int n,int A[]);

int main()
{
    size_t n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements you want in your array\n");
    if( scanf("%zu",&n) != 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in input");
    }
    if( n <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input : Enter number >= 0 .");
    }
    int a[n];
    printf("Enter the elements  in your array\n");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if( scanf("%d",&a[i]) != 1){
            fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in input");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    printMax(n,a);
    return 0;
}

void printMax(size_t n,int A[])
{
    int max=A[0];
    for(size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if(A[i] > max)
            max = A[i];

    printf("%d",max);
}
```

Comment: Minor: `size_t n;` would be more correct than `int n;`, yet for a learner `int` is OK.  It is the mixed `int n; ... size_t i` that should be resolved to one type for clarity.

Comment: @chux.: Yes good point..making `n` size_t is an idea. Changed the code. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

In `main()` you declare `n` but it has no value, so likely defaults to 0.  You then declare and define an array `A` and give it size `n`, which as I say is likely zero.

Within `max()` you then read in a value and assign it to `n` but your array `A` is size zero.

So change `main()` to

```
/* Get the number of items to store in the array */
int n;
printf("Enter the number of elements you want in your array\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

/* Create the array of the given size */
int A[n];

/* Now find the max value in that array */
max(n,A);
```

And remove the setting of `n` from `max()`.

Comment: I didn't get you. Please elaborate

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: As an aside, it might be worth considering moving the code where you're populating the array in to a separate method `populate_array`, again passing n and A to that method.  That makes more sense than being in the function that is actually meant to be just finding the max value.

Comment: *so likely defaults to 0* - no, it is not likely.

Comment: @EugeneSh obviously it's the compiler's call, and we don't know which compiler they're using, but if it was a positive non-zero number then there would be no segmentation fault, so I came to the conclusion that it had indeed defaulted to zero.

Comment: @LordWilmore That could also be a very large number overflowing the stack.

Comment: @chux great spot, updated the posted answer